# Animating <img> svg's with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, svg

I've read a [sweet tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/animating-svg-css/) about animating elements in a svg-image over at CSS-Tricks. The author addresses the different elements with CSS-classes added inside the svg. I would like to use that technique, but unfortunately on a background-image. So the svg is set as background-image in CSS and is not inline.
Is there a chance to achieve the same effect without putting the svg straight in my HTML? Maybe with jQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: If you put the CSS in the image file itself it will work. Interactivity like hover is ont possible though but you could run an animation continuously as the testcase does.

Comment: No, I don't want interactivity. It's a landscape to be precise and I just need some subtle movements. Do you have some sort of documentation or tutorial for adding the CSS in the svg? Like position in the document, markup and so on

Comment: You have a tutorial in question. There's also this if you want to use SMIL http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SMIL_animations

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
With CSS you are animating the actual element, not the SVG background. Just animate is like a normal HTMLElement:

This is a demo using a CSS transition over an SVG background:

http://jsfiddle.net/8dan1kx0/

```
div {
    background-image: url(http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 1s;
    border: 1px solid
}

div:hover{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I'd like to animate certain parts in the image.

Comment: No, in that case you can not access any of the SVG children to animate.